# How can i write a method that can generate scope dynamically which can be used for multiple models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

Currently, the existing scopes are like this.

```
module TransactionScopes
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      included do
        scope :status, ->(status) { where status: status }
        scope :portfolio_id, ->(portfolio_id) { where portfolio_id: portfolio_id }
        scope :investor_external_reference_id, ->(investor_external_reference_id) { where investor_external_reference_id: investor_external_reference_id }
        scope :portfolio_external_reference_id, ->(portfolio_external_reference_id) { where portfolio_external_reference_id: portfolio_external_reference_id }
        scope :file_id, ->(file_id) { where back_office_file_id: file_id }
        scope :oms_status, ->(status) { where oms_status: status }
        scope :order_id, ->(order_id) { where order_id: order_id }
        scope :order_status, ->(order_status) { where order_status: order_status }
        scope :transaction_id, ->(transaction_id) { where transaction_id: transaction_id }
end
```

I have some more models with similar scopes, can I write more generic way so I can avoid these repeated processes.

Comment: Maybe you can. It's the usual process: identify the differences and extract them as input parameters. Sometimes, it's not worth it, because the end result becomes much less readable.

Comment: Hey, @SergioTulentsev I want to write a generic class, which can be used in all the models to avoid writing scopes everywhere so that whenever a new attribute is added, we no need to add scope in the model every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly discourage you from adding a scope for each single attribute. `where(...)` is only 5 characters and provides additional context to the reader. `Person.where(name: 'John Doe')` says: on `Person` execute a query (`where`) and return a collection that matches the criteria `name: 'John Doe'`.

If you add the suggest attribute scope the line becomes `Person.name('John Doe')`. By removing the context that this is a query a reader must "learn" that each attribute name can also be accessed as a scope.

The above immediately shows another issue, which is name conflicts. `Person.name` is already taken, and returns the class name. So adding `scope :name, ->(name) { where(name: name) }` will raise an *ArgumentError*.

Scopes can be useful, but when used too much they clutter the class method namespace of the model.

With the above out of the way, here are some actual solutions.

---

You could write a helper that allows you to easily create scopes for attributes. Then loop through the passed attributes and dynamically create scopes for them.

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self

    private

    def attribute_scope_for(*attributes)
      attributes.each { |attr| scope attr, ->(value) { where(attr => value) } }
    end
  end
end
```

Then call this helper in your models.

```rb
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute_scopes_for :status, :portfolio_id # ....
end
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to create a scope for each attribute you can dynamically collect them using [`attribute_names`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute_names). Then loop through them and create scopes based on the names.

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self

    private

    def enable_attribute_scopes
      attribute_names
        .reject { |attr| respond_to?(attr, true) }
        .each { |attr| scope attr, ->(value) { where(attr => value) } }
    end
  end
end
```

In the above snippet `.reject { |attr| respond_to?(attr, true) }` is optional, but prevents the creation of scopes that have a name conflict with a current public/private class method. This will skip those attributes. You can safely omit this line, but the `scope` method might raise an *ArgumentError* when passing dangerous scope names.

Now the only thing left to do is calling `enable_attribute_scopes` in models where you want to enable attribute scopes.

---

The above should give you an idea of how you could handle things, you could even add options like `:except` or `:only`. There is also the option to extract the code above into a module and `extend AttributeScopeHelpers` within `ApplicationRecord` if the class becomes to cluttered.

However, like I started this answer I would advise against adding scopes for each attribute.